# How to make my flutter app cover the full android screen (Remove white bars on the side of the app)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a simple CRUD application, and while coding the UI, I keep running into this issue where my app doesn't take up the full screen of the android emulator, where there are white bars on the left and right of the scaffold (you can see this next to the appbar). It also exists when I add any other widgets in the body. Here is the issue I am facing:

[image]

Here is the scaffold in order to recreate this issue:

```dart
class StatisticView extends StatelessWidget {
  const StatisticView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool statisticAvailable = false;

  const Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color(0xffFAFAFA);
  const Color COLOR_GREEN = Color(0xff007336);
  const Color COLOR_BROWN = Color(0xff4B4539);
  const Color COLOR_BLACK = Color(0xff333333);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        backgroundColor: BACKGROUND_COLOR,
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 110,
          title: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
            child: Text(
              "Hours Leaderboard",
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: const Color(0xffFFFFFF)),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: COLOR_GREEN,
        ),
        body: statisticAvailable == false ? Center(child: Text("This feature is currently unavailable.")) : SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 175),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("3",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 8,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: COLOR_BROWN.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      spreadRadius: 8,
                                      blurRadius: 7,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      "https://www.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/florence-pugh.jpg"),
                                  radius: 55,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                child: Text("Florence",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: COLOR_BLACK,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              Text("20",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: COLOR_GREEN,
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, right: 175),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("2",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 8,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: COLOR_BROWN.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      spreadRadius: 8,
                                      blurRadius: 7,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F6%2F2019%2F07%2Fsimon-liu-2000.jpg"),
                                  radius: 55,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                child: Text("Simu",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: COLOR_BLACK,
                                    )),
                              ),
                              Text("48",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: COLOR_GREEN,
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              "assets/images/crown.png",
                              height: 35,
                              width: 35,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 8,
                            ),
                            Material(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                              elevation: 2,
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: COLOR_GREEN.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      spreadRadius: 8,
                                      blurRadius: 7,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                      "https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?q=85&c=sc&rect=255%2C0%2C1875%2C1080&poi=face&w=1920&h=1280&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F20%2F2021%2F09%2F13%2FJack-Harlow-chicken-shop-date.jpg"),
                                  radius: 60,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                              child: Text("Jack",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: COLOR_BLACK,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Text("52",
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  color: COLOR_GREEN,
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Runner-Ups",
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: COLOR_BLACK,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    PlayerStatistc(
                      placement: "4",
                      name: "Raj Bhawlaser",
                      hours: "15",
                      imageUrl:
                          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cmFuZG9tJTIwcGVvcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80",
                    ),
                    PlayerStatistc(
                      placement: "5",
                      name: "Bob Dylan",
                      hours: "13",
                      imageUrl:
                          "https://cdn4.pitchfork.com/longform/1005/BobDylan.jpg",
                    ),
                    PlayerStatistc(
                      placement: "6",
                      name: "Barack Obama",
                      hours: "11",
                      imageUrl:
                          "https://ca-times.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/bec99d7/2147483647/strip/true/crop/2000x2706+0+0/resize/840x1137!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalifornia-times-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fff%2F2c%2Fdedf568e4af087cab5f0a5c76f32%2Fla-ca-bk-a-promised-land-barack-obama-183.JPG",
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

1. Inside your project folder go to `android\app\src\main\res`.
2. You will find a bunch of folders, the only ones that you should be
   interested in are `values` and `values-night`.
3. Inside each folder is a `styles.xml` file. You just need to edit each file adding the line

   ```
   <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> to the <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
   ```
4. It should look like this:

```
  <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
      <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
  </style>
```

NOTE: If for some reason the first element inside a ListView (or similar Widget) has padding on the left side, just add zero padding to the list (`EdgeInsets.zero`).

Bonus: If you want to change between both modes (FullScreen and NotchFullScreen) you should look at this post `https://betterprogramming.pub/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c`.